# Is Keytool certificate is for free?

Tags: ssl, keytool

In our application we are creating Client and server that talks with each other using SSL authentication. I done a POC which downloads certificate using following commnand:

keytool -genkey -keystore yourKEYSTORE -keyalg RSA

Need to know if the certificate created by above command is free to use ?

Answer (score 2):

It's free to use but it is self-signed, which makes it basically useless unless you can go through all the steps required to get the peers to trust it.

Failing that, you need to generate a certificate request from this, get it signed, and import the resulting signed certificate into that keystore using the same alias you used here.